# Limit Access to a Group for a Project- Openstack 13 & 17

Tags: linux, redhat, openstack

i have a question for Openstack,
is it possible to limit access for a user to get read only on a specific project that he can only see the instances in that project and eliminate the actions edit,start,stop or delete instance ?

i have tried some tests grant *member* role only to the group but all users in the group were able to do everything with the instances

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the "[reader](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/ussuri/admin/service-api-protection.html#reader)" role.